# Safest and easiest method to neutralize nitric acid

Tags: acid-base, safety

I would like to know the safest method for neutralizing 70% nitric acid that is used in small amounts of 1-5 ml, for an electronics process in which there will be small traces of silicone and other similar trace materials dissolved into it, to safely contain for proper disposal to not be a risk for acid accidents or fire/explosion risks. Should a calcium carbonate-water mixture be used to increase $\mathrm{pH}$ slowly or is this method still unstable from higher purity of $\ce{HNO3}$ being involved or?

Comment: Dilute it with water then cautiously add carbonate until no further foaming occurs.

Comment: When diluted with at least 10 times its volume of water, nitric acid is not a fire/explosions risk any more, and it is not a risk for acid accidents.  Trace materials have no more effect on such diluted solutions.